# Make axis longer in 3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, plot

How can one adjust the length of the axes in a plot made with pgfplots/TikZ without affecting the plot itself?

Comment: You could use the `xmax`, `ymax`, `zmax` keys.

Comment: That solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several alternatives here: using the `xmax`, `ymax`, `zmax`, `xmin`, `ymin`, `zmin` keys or the family of keys `enlarge limits`, `enlarge x limits`, `enlarge y limits`, `enlarge z limits`. A little example (the example is 2D, but the same idea applies for 3D plots):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
\addplot+[no marks,domain=-2:2] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  xmax=6,
  ymax=6,
  xmin=-6,
  ymin=-6
  ]
\addplot+[no marks,domain=-2:2] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  enlarge x limits=3,
  enlarge y limits=3
  ]
\addplot+[no marks,domain=-2:2] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]